# AssertJ: a collection contains an element with the value ending with a string

Tags: java, assertj

I want to check if a collection under test contains any element which ends with a particular string.

With Hamcrest it could be like:

```
assertThat("Contains an element ending with 'xyz'", 
               myCollection, hasItems(endsWith("xyz")));
```

How to do the same with AssertJ?

Answer (score 8):

You can use [`anyMatch(Predicate)`](https://www.javadoc.io/static/org.assertj/assertj-core/3.14.0/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractIterableAssert.html#anyMatch(java.util.function.Predicate)) or [`anySatisfy(assertions on elements)`](https://www.javadoc.io/static/org.assertj/assertj-core/3.14.0/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractIterableAssert.html#anySatisfy(java.util.function.Consumer)), ex:

```java
assertThat(myCollection).as("Contains an element ending with 'xyz'") 
                        .anyMatch(element -> element.endsWith("xyz"));
```